# Repeating rows with bootstrap

Tags: jsf-2, jstl, el, facelets

I am attempting to format my site to nicely play with the [bootstrap custom content component](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails-custom-content). Trouble is the xml is being parsed and doesn't like the fact that I haven't closed my div tag. This assumes that I have multiples of 3 in my groups.

Code (updated to my complete code):

```
 <ui:repeat var="crs" value="#{groups.getGroupRows(true)}" varStatus="status">

                    <c:if test="${(status.index mod 3) == 0}">
                        <div class="row">
                    </c:if>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <ui:repeat value="#{crs.getObject('imageFiles').files}" var="image">  
                                <h:link outcome="viewClassesInGroup" id="group_name" styleClass="thumbnail">
                                    <f:param name="group_id" id="group_id" value="#{crs.getInteger('group_id')}"/>
                                    <img src="#{image.imageAbsoluteUrl('large')}" data-src="holder.js/300x200" />
                                </h:link>
                            </ui:repeat>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3><h:link outcome="viewClassesInGroup"  id="group_name" value="#{crs.string}">
                                        <f:param name="group_id" id="group_id" value="#{crs.getInteger('group_id')}"/>
                                    </h:link></h3>
                                <p><h:outputText id="group_description" value="#{crs.string}"/></p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Group</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <c:if test="${(status.index mod 3) == 0}">
                        </div>
                    </c:if>

                </ui:repeat>
```

Error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Error Parsing /index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 31] The element type "div" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</div>".] with root cause
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 31] The element type "div" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</div>".
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:450)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doMetadataCompile(SAXCompiler.java:433)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.metadataCompile(Compiler.java:130)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:495)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$200(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:203)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:92)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:146)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:63)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:316)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:246)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:241)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**Update**

I have tried matching the expression, as well as switching places of the test. It still is throwing a javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /index.xhtml

Comment: @Prasad for some reason I do not believe the c:if has the logic to see its other conditionals. I moved to using a double for loop for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I switched to uses a double for loop and 4 columns instead of 3.

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="#{(groups.getGroupRows(true).size() / 4) +(1-((groups.getGroupRows(true).size() / 4) %1))%1}">
                    <div class="row">
                        <c:forEach var="x" begin="${((i - 1) * 4)}" end="${(((i - 1) * 4) + 3)}">
                            <c:if test="${(groups.getGroupRows(true).size() - 1) ge x}">
                                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                    <div class="thumbnail">
                                        <ui:repeat value="#{groups.getGroupRows(true).get(x).getObject('imageFiles').files}" var="image">  
                                            <h:link outcome="viewClassesInGroup" id="group_name">
                                                <f:param name="group_id" value="#{groups.getGroupRows(true).get(x).getInteger('group_id')}"/>
                                                <img src="#{image.imageAbsoluteUrl('large')}"/>
                                            </h:link>
                                        </ui:repeat>
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <h3><h:link outcome="viewClassesInGroup" value="#{groups.getGroupRows(true).get(x).getString('group_name')}">
                                                    <f:param name="group_id" value="#{groups.getGroupRows(true).get(x).getInteger('group_id')}"/>
                                                </h:link></h3>
                                            <p><h:outputText value="#{groups.getGroupRows(true).get(x).getString('group_description')}"/></p>
                                            <p><h:link outcome="viewClassesInGroup" styleClass="btn btn-primary" p:role="button" value="View Group">
                                                    <f:param name="group_id" value="#{groups.getGroupRows(true).get(x).getInteger('group_id')}"/>
                                                </h:link>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </c:if>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
```

While it is not as elegant as I would like. It still solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am new here,

I have searched for a solution for several rows with bootstrap in jsf. When I looked at the solution here, I did not even look through this, because it looks a little overloaded. Why I came up with my own solution. I hope it is clearer.

MySolution:

```
<div class="container">
  <ui:repeat step="3" value="#{bean.list}" varStatus="outerLoopIndex">
      <div class="row">
          <ui:repeat offset="#{outerLoopIndex.index}" size="#{(outerLoopIndex.index + 3) gt bean.list.size() ? bean.list.size() : outerLoopIndex.index + 3}" 
          var="item" value="#{bean.list}" varStatus="innerLoopIndex">
           <div class="col-4">
            <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
                #{innerLoopIndex.index} #{item.foo}
            </label>
           </div>
          </ui:repeat>
      </div>
  </ui:repeat>
</div> <!-- container -->
```

If you want to change the number of columns by row, the step must be adjusted in the outer repeat element, the size in the inner repeat element and, of course, the col class of the div element.

Change COLUMNSPERROW:

```
<ui:repeat step="COLUMNSPERROW" var="permission" value="#{bean.list}" varStatus="outerLoopIndex">
      <div class="row">
          <ui:repeat offset="#{outerLoopIndex.index}" size="#{(outerLoopIndex.index + COLUMNSPERROW) gt bean.list.size() ? bean.list.size() : outerLoopIndex.index + COLUMNSPERROW}" 
          var="item" value="#{bean.list}" varStatus="innerLoopIndex">
           <div class="col">
```

Answer (score -1):

The first if and second would never match up on the same index and it fact the  would end up appearing before the  because of the (status.index + 1)

So you'd end up with

```
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        ...
    </div>
<div>
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

OR some something like that which would explain the error you're getting.

Comment: Yes, but they are not suppose to.... even with the same expression for both c:if statements it will output the same error

Comment: Have you tried switch places of the tests so it's (status.index + 1) (status.index)? or even swap position of the 2 if? either might get it to output them in the right order which I'm thinking is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Just another thought how are you handling if there's less than 3 at the end? might be you need to insure that last one you openned is being closed.